# How to use else inside Python's timeit

Tags: python, timeit

I am new to using the timeit module, and I'm having a hard time getting multi-line code snippets to run inside timeit.

What works:

```
timeit.timeit(stmt = "if True: print('hi');")
```

What does not work (these all fail to even run):

```
timeit.timeit(stmt = "if True: print('hi'); else: print('bye')")
timeit.timeit(stmt = "if True: print('hi') else: print('bye')")
timeit.timeit(stmt = "if True: print('hi');; else: print('bye')")
```

I have found that I can use triple-quotes to encapsulate multi-line code segments, but I'd rather just type on one line.

Is there any way to use an else statement inside one line in timeit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The string you provide is interpreted as a source code, so you can use multiline strings with three quotation marks, like

```
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt = """if True: 'hi'
... else: 'bye'""")
0.015218939913108187
```

**or** `\n` for newlines (but it looks pretty messy)

```
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt = "if True: 'hi'\nelse: 'bye'")
0.015617805548572505
```

---

You can also use ternary `if-else` condition if you need only a single branch (so no newline is required):

```
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt = "'hi' if True else 'bye'")
0.030958037935647553
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember about conditional expression: `<true val> if <condition> else <false val>`

When used with timeit it may look as

```
timeit.timeit("print('true') if 2+2 == 4 else print('false')")
```

Notes:

- this example will work in python3, I wanted to use `print` as a function, because it was easiest. Of course you can `from __future__ import print_function` in p2.x
- this example will obviously output a s*itload od "true"s, be careful while running it

Answer (score 0):

This code will work the way you want:

```
timeit.timeit("""
if True: print('hi')
else: print('bye')
""")
```

Necessarily the presence of a new line

Answer (score 0):

My answer was found within an answer for [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301896/using-semicolons-inside-timeit)

You need to have a new line in between the `if` and `else`, so it works to do

`timeit.timeit(stmt = "if True: print('hi');\nelse: print('bye')")`